# Merging without column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with timestamped data. I want to select all the values where both dataframes had a timestamp within a difference less than some threshold.

For example, dataframes 1 and 2 look like this, except with different, unpredictable clock values:

```
   clock      head        px        py        pz        qw         
0      0.000000 -0.316579  0.119198  0.149585  0.271688  0.987492 -0.002514   
1      0.200000 -0.316642  0.119212  0.149593  0.271678  0.987487 -0.002522   
2      1.200000 -0.316546  0.119199  0.149585  0.271669  0.987495 -0.002507   


   clock      head        px        py        pz        qw         
0      0.010000 -0.316579  0.119198  0.149585  0.271688  0.987492 -0.002514   
1      1.1040000 -0.316642  0.119212  0.149593  0.271678  0.987487 -0.002522   
2      2.4030000 -0.316546  0.119199  0.149585  0.271669  0.987495 -0.002507
```

The resulting dataframe looks like assuming a threshold of 0.1:

```
   clock      head1        head2        px1        px2        ...         
0      0.000000 -0.316579 -0.316579  0.119198  0.119198  ...
1      1.200000 -0.316546 -0.316642  0.119199  0.119212  ...
```

My current methodology is: create an identical "filler" column in both dataframes, merge on this column (creating an len(dataframe1)*len(dataframe2) length dataframe) and then filter on the columns I want:

```
#rename the dataframe keys so that they are different
dataframe1.columns = [i+str(1) for i in dataframe1.columns.values]
dataframe1['filler'] = 0
dataframe2.columns = [i+str(2) for i in dataframe2.columns.values]
dataframe2['filler'] = 0
# merge requires a column to merge on, so merge on the filler
df_merged = dataframe1.merge(dataframe2,on='filler',how='left')
#pick out only the rows with the time differences within the threshold
mask = (df_merged[keyword+str(1)]<= df_merged[keyword+str(2)]+threshold) & (df_merged[keyword+str(1)]> df_merged[keyword+str(2)]-threshold)
df_merged = df_merged[mask]
#delete the filler column
del df_merged['filler']
#reindex the dataframe
df_merged.index = arange(0, len(df_merged))
```

This is very fast and gives me the output I want, however, it feels silly to create a 'filler' column that I then have to delete. I'm wondering if there was a more obvious solution that I missed.

Merging on the 'keyword' column does not give me what I want, this only produces a dataframe with complete data only if the times are exactly the same, without the threshold on time difference.

Comment: Please add a small example of what data you have, and how you want it to look afterwards.

Comment: I've added some sample dataframes (with the same data, real dataframes have different values)

Comment: It feels like naming the columns `"head1"`, and `"head2"` is the problem. Maybe if you tell us what you want to do with the columns afterwards, it will be easier to give you a better solution. I have a feeling you actually want to concat the dataframes and then reduce them down to solid second observations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where` to change your `df2`'s `clock` column data to match `df1`'s if it's within the threshold to fuzzy match.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# THE TEST DATA YOU GAVE US -------------------------
columns = ['clock', 'head', 'px', 'py', 'pz', 'qw']

series1 = [(0.0, 0.1, 0.5),
           (-0.316579, -0.316642, -0.316546),
           (0.119198, 0.119212, 0.119199),
           (0.149585, 0.149593, 0.149585),
           (0.271688, 0.271678, 0.271669),
           (0.987492, 0.987487, 0.987495),
           (-0.002514, -0.002522, -0.002507)]

series2 = [(0.01, 0.104, 0.403),
           (-0.316579, -0.316642, -0.316546),
           (0.119198, 0.119212, 0.119199),
           (0.149585, 0.149593, 0.149585),
           (0.271688, 0.271678, 0.271669),
           (0.987492, 0.987487, 0.987495),
           (-0.002514, -0.002522, -0.002507)]
# THE TEST DATA YOU GAVE US -------------------------

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(columns, series1)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(columns, series2)))

threshold = 0.99

df2['clock'] = np.where(
    abs(df1['clock'] - df2['clock']) < threshold, df1['clock'], df2['clock'])

merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on='clock', how='outer')
print(merged_df)

   clock    head_x      px_x      py_x      pz_x      qw_x    head_y        px_y      py_y      pz_y      qw_y   
0    0.0 -0.316579  0.119198  0.149585  0.271688  0.987492 -0.316579 0  0.119198  0.149585  0.271688  0.987492   
1    0.1 -0.316642  0.119212  0.149593  0.271678  0.987487 -0.316642 1  0.119212  0.149593  0.271678  0.987487   
2    0.5 -0.316546  0.119199  0.149585  0.271669  0.987495 -0.316546 2  0.119199  0.149585  0.271669  0.987495
```

This has the benefit of not merging any rows that don't match the threshold, so if you had DataFrames which also had rows of data with `df1['clock'] == 6` and `df2['clock'] == 7` (outside of the `0.99` threshold), you'll end up with two more rows, one with `clock == 6` and all the `_y`'s full of `NaN`s, and one with `clock == 7` and all the `_x's` full of `NaN`s

Comment: This does not work, it assumes that df1 and df2 are the same size and are sorted. I will update my sample data to reflect this.

Comment: @CatherineHolloway your sample data no longer makes sense, since the result frame `clock` values don't correspond with anything